# VB.NET - How to Hide a Form in Cross-Thread Operation

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multithreading

I need a function to Hide a form in cross -thread operation. I write this code but it close the form and not only hide it:

```
 Dim objHideMyForm As delegateUpdateApps = AddressOf HideFree

 Private Sub HideFree()
   Try
     Me.Hide()
   Catch
   End Try
 End Sub

Public Sub HideMe()
   Me.Invoke(objHideMyForm)
End Sub
```

Comment: Please **do not** catch every exception and simply throw it away... doubly so if this is a prototype and/or throw-away application.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour. Are you sure that this is the code that executes?

Comment: The try catch is not important now... When i invoke che delegate and the function goes on Me.Hide the form does not Hide butthe Form Close.

Comment: x Fredrik : Yes this is the code that i execute... Maybe you have to declare the delegateUpdateApps.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would simply call:

```
Me.ParentForm.Close()
```